# What is correct syntax for a, b = (1, 2, 3, ...)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, unpack, iterable-unpacking

I want to do something like this:

```
a, b, = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n)
```

```
# a = 1
# b = 2
```

Is this possible in Python 3 ?

Comment: Is this not typical use of indices ? `a =  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n)`, then `a[0]=1, a[1]=2` etc. ?

Comment: You can do: `a, b, *_ = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n)`, where extra values go into _, and a will be 1 and b will be 2.

Answer (score 7):

As documented in [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), since Python 3, you can use a third variable to collect the rest:

```
a, b, *_ = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

print(a, b)
# 1 2

print(_)
# [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.0, the * operator was added to the multiple assignment syntax, allowing us to capture remaining items after an unpacking into a list:

```
>>> numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> first, *rest = numbers
>>> rest
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> first
1
```

Answer (score -3):

Solution:

```
# Input data: seq => tuple 
seq = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# Store a list of letters between a-z up the same length as the sequence: letter_list => list
letter_list = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)))[0:len(seq)]

# Iterate through each element in the letter list storing the letter 
# as variable in the global env: letter_list => var
for n, val in enumerate(letter_list):
    globals()[val] = seq[n]

# Print variables to console: stdout
print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Comment: Why downvoted does this not provide the required solution?